# Custom header converter Java DSL- Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, header, http-headers, spring-integration

Hey I've got WARNs like that:

> Header "errorChannel" with value [reference to hash Object] **will not
> be set since it is not a String and no Converter is available.
> Consider registering a Converter with ConversionService**
>
> Header "replyChannel" with value [reference to hash Object] **will not
> be set since it is not a String and no Converter is available.
> Consider registering a Converter with ConversionService**

My goal is to keep these headers and I won't excluding them. And turn on something conversion to setting for e.g. empty "" string for this headers objects.

Currently I take all headers like that

```
customOutbound.getMappedRequestHeaders("*")
```

I read about that spring ofers some patterns in

> DeafaultHttpHeaderMapper.class

But if I want cutomize converter I must implement HeaderMapper?

If someone could show me an example with a custom implementation for converting selected headers to a string. It would be great. Thank you guys for support.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to send an HTTP request and you want to send some headers over there. So, you use that `DeafaultHttpHeaderMapper` which give us a message you mention:

```
private void setPlainHeader(HttpHeaders target, String name, Object value) {
    String convertedValue = convertToString(value);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(convertedValue)) {
        target.set(name, convertedValue);
    }
    else {
        this.logger.warn("Header '" + name + "' with value '" + value +
                "' will not be set since it is not a String and no Converter is available. " +
                "Consider registering a Converter with ConversionService (e.g., <int:converter>)");
    }
}
```

To add a custom convert you just need to declare this `DeafaultHttpHeaderMapper` as a bean and register the mentioned in that message `<int:converter>` or `@IntegrationConverter` bean: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#payload-type-conversion

From here there is still a question why would one transfer over the network those internal volatile `replyChannel` and `errorChannel` headers? Why really just not ignore them?

For some sophisticated use-cases we suggest this feature of the Header Enricher: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-channel-registry